# Is it possible for a link to be grouped in with two radio buttons using fieldset

Tags: html, css

I want a link to be grouped in with two radio buttons using fieldset
There is no name Attribute for a href link

```
<div class="fieldset-auto-width">
<fieldset id="group1">
<div class="tc tc7">
<span class="button">
<a href="called_form.php?var=XXXXX&var2=XXXX" target="_blank"></a>
</span></div>
<div class="tc tc8">
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="a"/></div>
<div class="tc8a">
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="d"/></div>
</fieldset> <!-- end fieldset id -->
</div> <!-- end fieldset-auto-width -->
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off topic because SO is here to to help you with markup you wrote but SO is not here to write markup for you.

Comment: Rob, what would of been the correct way to do this? I mean get help

Answer (score 0):

```css
html, body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0
}

.div-table {
   display: table;
   width: 85%;
}

.tr {display: table-row;}

.tc {
   display:table-cell;
   vertical-align:top;
   padding: 1px 10px;
}

.tc1 {width:240px;}
.tc4, .tc5, .tc6 {width: 85px;}


.tc7 {width: 100px;}

.tc8 {width: 230px;}

.tc8a {width: 30px;
       display:table-cell;
       padding-top: 1px;
       padding-right:-15px;
}

#div_line {
   MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0.5%; WIDTH: 100%;}

.fieldset-auto-width {
         display: inline-block;
         vertical-align:top;
         margin-top: -5px;
         margin-left: -8px;
         width: 173%;
}
.button a{
  font: bold 11px Arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: #333333;
  padding: 1px 6px 1px 6px;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #333333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  width: 5em;
  margin-left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<form action="http://localhost/lineup2.php" method="post">
   <div class="div-table">
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="tc tc1">Category</div>
      <div class="tc tc2">Website</div>
      <div class="tc tc3">Website</div>
      <div class="tc tc4">Category</div>
      <div class="tc tc5">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="tc tc6">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="tc">Name</div>
      <div class="tc">Name</div>
      <div class="tc">Address</div>
      <div class="tc">Override</div>
      <div class="tc">Add</div>
      <div class="tc">Delete</div>
    </div><br/>
    
    <div class="tr">
    <div class="tc"> Online Networking Groups (Free)</div>
    <div class="tc"> jerome test 1</div>
    <div class="tc"> bvhvhvh</div>
    <div class="tc tc7">
    <span class="button">
    <a href="called_form.php?var=jerome&var2=greene" target="_blank"></a>
     </span></div>
     <div class="fieldset-auto-width">
     <fieldset id="group1">
     <div class="tc tc8">
     <input type="radio" name="group1" value="a"/></div>
      <div class="tc8a">
      <input type="radio" name="group1" value="d"/></div>
 </fieldset> <!-- end fieldset id -->
</div> <!-- end fieldset-auto-width -->
</div> <!-- end tr -->

 <div class="tr">
 <div class="tc"> Associations, Groups &amp; Societies</div>
<div class="tc"> jerome test 2</div>
<div class="tc"> hbhggggg</div>
<div class="tc tc7">
<span class="button">
<a href="called_form.php?var=jerome&var2=greene" target="_blank"></a>
</span></div>
<div class="fieldset-auto-width">
<fieldset id="group2">
<div class="tc tc8">
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="a"/></div>
<div class="tc8a">
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="d"/></div>
</fieldset> <!-- end fieldset id -->
</div> <!-- end fieldset-auto-width -->
</div> <!-- end tr -->
```

I have it working now. Here is the code. This is what I was looking for
This will work on a multi row form

```
<div class="tc tc7">
<span class="button">
<a href="called_form.php?var=jerome&var2=greene" target="_blank"></a>
</span></div>

<div class="fieldset-auto-width">
<fieldset id="group1">
<div class="tc tc8">
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="a"/></div>
<div class="tc8a">
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="d"/></div>
</fieldset> <!-- end fieldset id -->
</div> <!-- end fieldset-auto-width -->
```

Comment: Will you add snipet?

Comment: Little bit new to this. What do you want to see. I can add the code and css and output?

Comment: I will implement my project I have same idea.